# Analytic function defined in the domain satisfying lim sup f(z) =0 is constantly zero.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

I'd love to solve the following question:

> Let $f$ be an analytic function defined in the domain $\{z | |Re (z)|
> < 1 , Im(z) > 0 \}$. If $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0 , \epsilon >0}
> \sup_{1/3 <x< 2/3}|f(x+ i \epsilon)| = 0,$$ Then $f\equiv 0$.

By the assumption, we know that for each $x\in(1/3,2/3)$, there is a sequence $f(x+a_{x,n}i) \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. To get the result, my guess is we need to use Maximum modulus principle. But I don't know how to start proof.

Comment: Try using the Schwartz reflection principle and show the resulting function is identically zero

Comment: @Zarrax Thanks for your comment. Could I check the detail? Since we have lim sup condition and $f$ is continuous, we can extend the function $f$ to the real line $1/3<x<2/3$, right? Also, $f(x) = 0 $ on the real line. By Schwarz reflection principle, $f$ is also extended to $\{z | 1/3 < x<2/3\}.$ Then $f$ is analytic on that domain $D=\{z | 1/3 < x<2/3\}$. Since [1/3,2/3] is inside the domain $D$ and $f(x)=0$ on that line segment, $f$ is identically zero.

Comment: That's the argument I had in mind.

Comment: @Zarrax Thank you.